# Questions about positive integers $a,b,c$ s.t. $ab+1,bc+1,ca+1$ are perfect squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

So I am doing several questions about elementary number theory, and I am stuck in a question:

> For positive integers $a,b,c$, prove that if $(ab+1)(bc+1)(ca+1)$ are perfect square, then $ab+1$, $bc+1$, $ca+1$ are all perfect squares

I have no idea on how to solve the problem. I try to assume $(ab+1)(bc+1)(ca+1)=(abc+k)^2$ and I get
$$\dfrac{k^2-1}{abc}-\dfrac{1}{a}-\dfrac{1}{b}-\dfrac{1}{c}=a+b+c-2k$$
to make the right hand side a positive integer but it leads to nothing. Any ideas or solutions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is a famous, difficult problem by Kiran Kedlaya. A solution for it can be found here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c146h150369_a_1

Comment: How is this quantified? If the product IS a perfect square, then terms are perfect squares, as well?

Comment: @AlvinL the converse is trivially true but the problem might not be true cuz $12^2=144=6\times 8\times 3$ but $6,8,3$ aren't perfect squares, which is why this problem is hard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$(xy + 1)(yz + 1)(zx + 1)$ is a perfect square if and only if each factor is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92270/xy-1yz-1zx-1-is-a-perfect-square-if-and-only-if-each-factor-is) - found by using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24ab%2B1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24bc%2B1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Asquare&p=1). Also, [Show that if $x,y,z$ are positive integers, then $(xy + 1)(yz + 1)(zx + 1)$ is a perfect square iff $xy +1, yz +1, zx+1$ are all perfect squares.](/q/1704159) asks this as the first of two questions.